# Navigating between activities in different packages

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-bottom-nav-view

What is the best way to implement bottom navigation between activities that reside in different packages ? Where the packages import one another in a top down fashion.

### Setup

I have structured my project as a set of packages; Essentially split into the main `app`, a number of intermediate `PACKAGE`s and the final `end` package :

- `app` - Provides the main application and serves as the projects build target. It contains a single activity, `Main`, providing the primary entry point for the application. The navigation graph simply maps the only fragment to the `ACTIVITY`'s provided by each of the imported `PACKAGE`'s.
- `PACKAGE` - Provides a single activity, `ACTIVITY`, to manage a dedicated task. The navigation graph manages the relationships between the various fragments supporting the activity; *Additionally* it includes link to the `Final` activity imported from `end`.
- `end` - Provides a single activity, `Final`, which each `PACKAGE` importing it uses as the terminating navigation link for their navigation graphs.

So each package contains a single activity, one or more fragments and a navigation graph that manages the routing between them and a node pointing to the activity in the next package in the order `app.Main > PACKAGE.ACTIVITY > end.Final`.

### Navigation

Given this structure I want to add bottom navigation, `|Main|...|Final|`, to each activity `ACTIVITY` such that there is a link back to `Main` and another onward to `Final`. Linking forward to `Final` is easy enough as enough as it's already a target in each `PACKAGE`s navigation graph but I am uncertain on the best method for linking back to `Main`. Similarly I want to provide bottom navigation, `|Main|ACTIVITY|...|`, to `Final` such that the user go back to either the preceding `ACTIVITY` or `Main`.

### Considerations

1. What is the best means of providing navigation targets to the activities in the parent packages ? To me the following seem viable

   1. Cross import all of the packages within gradle. That is `app` imports each `PACKAGE` and `end`, every `PACKAGE` imports both `app` and `end`, and `end` imports each `PACKAGE` and `app`. This is not very DRY but it will make all activities universally accessible.
   2. Pass `Main` as a list to `ACTIVITY`, adding it to the navigation menu programatically. Similarly pass `Main` and `ACTIVITY` as a list to `Final`. Here I'm not sure, given that activites have lifecycles, if I should pass the activity class or the instance thereof to the child activity ? The advantage here is that I can readily create the backstack if it's missing.
   3. Interrogate the "Activity" back stack as it already details the route to both `ACTIVITY` (That is it contains `Main`) and `Final` (That is it contains `Main` and `ACTIVITY`). Here it becomes tricky to create the backstack after the fact.
   4. Use deep linking ? (I'm still reading up on this)
   5. Should one simply cross reference each activity setting `parentAttribute` under the `<activity/>` in each `PACKAGES`'s `manifest.xml` to provide the necessary navigation targets ? Here I'm not sure how best to add this to the bottom navigation graph/menu ? Also it becomes necessary to programmatically set the `parentAttrbiute` depending upon the route taken to reach `Final`.
2. Depending on how access to the activities is provided in 1 I'm not sure what the best means is of making such target accessible ?

   1. Can this be done within a navigation graph ? Can I programmatically add activities from a parent package to the navigation graph ? Can a `Placeholder` be used to reference such items ? Can a custom navigation destination can be written to represent such items.
   2. Should one simply populate the menu provided to the navigation menu used by `BottomNavigationView` ? Can one do this and support targets provided by a navigation graph, that is can one overwrite both `OnNavigationItemSelectedLsitener` and use `setupWithNavController` together ?

**Note :** While I have seen some similar questions and answers I haven't seen any that deal with activities in separate packages.

Comment: If you're down voting please state why...

Comment: I didn't down vote you but please state your problem in more simplest way and put more codes in the question for the person who gonna help you understand what you are asking.

Comment: Hmm.. I thought I had formulated the question fairly well... none the less I rewrote/restructured the question section using numbered lists and sectioned the entire thing into subheadings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by interrogating the package manager to determine the activities that are available within my application, under my package name.

Adding metadata to each activity, under the `MANIFEST.xml`, allowed me to filter the activities I wanted to reference. Adding `android:label` and `android:icon` attributes allowed me to provide labels and icons for the buttons in the navigation view and to display them upon the app bar. Furthermore I could create intents for each activity and set these upon the menu items (One of the android docs mentioned that any menuItem that is not handled directly will have its intent attribute invoked).

I wrapped all of this into an interface and can now tack that onto the activities I wish to navigate too outside of the navigation graphs supported by the navigation components.

**Note :** It's possible deep links serve this purpose but I haven't seena  nice example just yet.